# Arquillian can't inject a local or remote EJB on Glassfish embedded container

Tags: junit, junit4, jboss-arquillian, glassfish-embedded, arquillian-drone

I use Arquillian to test an EJB that has an explicit local and remote interface. But in the test Arquillian does not "inject" anything in a field that has the type of the local interface, or the remote interface.

I use the Glassfish embedded as server for test and I use junit4.

I used :

1. `@EJB` ,
2. `@Inject` ,
3. `@EJB(lookup="java:global/costa-services-depa/GreeterImpl!es.costa.GreeterLocal")` ,
4. `@EJB(lookup="java:global/costa-services-depa/GreeterImpl!es.costa.GreeterRemote")`

With (2) even for `GreeterImpl`, or `GreeterLocal` or `GreeterRemote` it gives me the error `Could not inject members`.

With (1,3,4) I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` which means that the EJB is not injected.

This is a part of my code:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class greeterTest {
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
    JavaArchive jar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class,"costa-services-depa")
        .addClasses(
                GreeterRemote.class,
                GreeterLocal.class,
                Greeter.class)
        .addAsManifestResource("test-persistence.xml", "persistence.xml")
        .addAsManifestResource("jbossas-ds.xml")
        .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/beans.xml",
                ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));
    return jar;
}

@Inject
GreeterImpl greeter;


@Test
public void testTestServiceLocal(){
    System.out.println(greeter.getMessage());
} 
}
```

Here is the `glassfish-resources.xml`:

```
...
<resources>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="ArquillianEmbeddedH2Pool"
    jndi-name="jdbc/arquillian"/>
<jdbc-connection-pool name="ArquillianEmbeddedH2Pool"
    res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    datasource-classname="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
    <property name="user" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:file:target/databases/h2/db"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Here is the `test-persistence.xml`:

```
...
<persistence-unit name="test">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/arquillian</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is the `arquillian.xml`:

```
...
<container qualifier="glassfish-embedded" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="resourcesXml">
            ejbModule/src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>
...
```

This is `jbossas-ds.xml`:

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema
    http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
<datasource enabled="true"
    jndi-name="jdbc/arquillian"
    pool-name="ArquillianEmbeddedH2Pool">
    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:arquillian;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
    <driver>h2</driver>
</datasource>
</datasources>
```

About dependencies for Glassfish embedded and Arquillian and Junit:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.166</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>ejbModule/src/test/resources</directory>
                </testResource>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>ejbModule/src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <arquillian.launch>glassfish-embedded</arquillian.launch>
                            <java.util.logging.config.file>
                                ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties
                            </java.util.logging.config.file>
                            <derby.stream.error.file>
                                ${project.build.directory}/derby.log
                            </derby.stream.error.file>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In the console I noticed:

```
Infos: Network listener https-listener on port 0 disabled per domain.xml
Infos: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 32ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]
Infos: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (java_re) startup time : 
Embedded (525ms), startup services(384ms), total(909ms)
Infos: command add-resources result: 
PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSDescription: add-resources AdminCommandnull
JDBC connection pool ArquillianEmbeddedH2Pool created successfully.
JDBC resource jdbc/arquillian created successfully.
Infos: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
Infos: SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service
Infos: SEC1143: Loading policy provider 
com.sun.enterprise.security.jacc.provider.SimplePolicyProvider.
Infos: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype 
[com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
[com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Infos: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype 
[com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Infos: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype 
[com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Infos: SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully
Infos: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]
Infos: WEB0171: Created virtual server [server]
Infos: WEB0172: Virtual server [server] loaded default web module []
Infos: WELD-000900 SNAPSHOT
Infos: WEB0671: Loading application [**test**] at [**/test**]
Infos: test was successfully deployed in 1 822 milliseconds.
PlainTextActionReporterSUCCESSNo monitoring data to report.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.308 sec
Infos: Shutdown procedure finished
Infos: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] exiting
```

NB : By default that deploys as **test** application or not as what I made "costa-services-depa"?

To know that in the path of call of EJB I put test instead of costa-service-depa but always it gives me the same problem (`NullPointerException`).

Comment: Sorry, I've not a lot experience with Glassfish (embedded exactly) and problem looks strange. By description you do all right. But for experiment can you switch to another type of application server and test again? WildFly/JBoss would be preferred.

Comment: Sorry , with jboss managed it works good but the company wants to use glassfish embedded

Comment: Try it! My experience tells that JBoss/WildFly can show you some hidden problems, take another look on problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem trying to somehow inject a context bean in an Arquillian test against GlassFish 4.1. 
This issue seems related to a GlassFish (major and open) bug:

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21167

They say injections in GlassFish won't work deploying a war with certain conditions:

1. The application uses an empty `<absoluteOrdering>` tag in `web.xml`
2. The classes of the application are all packed as jar archives in the `[war]\WEB-INF\lib\` directory, instead of included them unpacked in the `[war]\WEB-INF\classes\` directory

What happens to me is that my `@Singleton` bean is created and injected but for *every* `@EJB` reference in the app, not just created once.
I checked my Arquillian deployment on GF (`glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\test`) and I can see the `test.jar` deployed in `[war]\WEB-INF\lib\`. I don't have a `web.xml` in my app and I don't see it in my GlassFish deployment. I guess the `web.xml` is provided somehow automatically.

Deploying the same app with Arquillian on Wildfly works fine and my `@Singleton` bean is injected correctly as expected.